# Cannot see a public Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a bucket and made it public. I created a user XYZ and i can't see the public bucket from that users' account. When a bucket is public all the users should be seeing it from their accounts irrespective of policies attached to them. Am I wrong

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "all the users should be seeing it from their accounts"? What are they doing (eg looking at S3 buckets in the console or using an AWS CLI command)? What permissions does that user have? Also, how did you "make it public" — did you use a Bucket Policy or was it a Permissions setting in the S3 console? Feel free to edit the question to add more details. (Basically, making bucket content publicly accessible is distinct from seeing the bucket in a listing of S3 buckets in an account. However, I'd like to know more about your situation.)

Answer (score 1):

> When a bucket is public all the users should be seeing it from their accounts irrespective of policies attached to them

Actually XYZ should be able to see the **contents** of the public bucket. The bucket itself would not be listed under the S3 buckets of XYZ.

Answer (score 0):

If you made the bucket public by going to the permissions tab of the bucket properties and changing the bucket Access Control List to public from there then check the following:

- Remove your bucket policy or check it , best way is to remove it for trouble shooting in a dev environment
- When looking at the bucket do you see an orange Public marker on the permissions tab or bucket overview
- Check that in the access control list under permissions under Public access  check:

  - List objects = yes

It would be safer to share the bucket explicitly to the other accounts (see 
 [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html)) the reason for this is that the entire world can see your bucket contents and there is an army of people scanning for buckets just like yours and sucking down all the content... Plenty of large corporations have ended up in the newspaper because of this.

If you still can't get it to work get them to give you the output of the following command so we can debug:

```
# aws s3 cp s3://mypublicbucket/mytestdocument.txt ./mytestdocument.txt
```

And also if they try and get the object from their browser then show us the error displayed in the browser. Also let us know if it works when you try from your own browser?